# Working with Backbone Events to trigger post with different methods appended to Collections URL

Tags: rest, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I am working with a handful of RESTFul API's that are as follows in concept.

`domain.com/api/?id=xxxxx` as the getter API call for the model/collection

In this case for me though there is several POST based setters that look like.

```
domain.com/api/start?id=xxxxx
domain.com/api/stop?id=xxxxx
domain.com/api/method?id=xxxxx
domain.com/api/thing1?id=xxxxx
domain.com/api/thing2?id=xxxxx
```

So I am trying to figure out how to trigger a POST based on the collection/model URL but appending start, stop, method, thing1, thing2 to it.. along with the id= as depicted.

Comment: That API seems not RESTful then.

Comment: RESTFul Yes, CRUD like not so much

Comment: Ultimately the API I am working with isn't backbone friendly. Just hoping to come up with a not so invasive means of dealing with it

Comment: backbone's [`emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP) might help in this situation